# Java : gridbaglayout confusion

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

this is my first question on here, so please forgive me when i am breaking any rules, or not using the right format

I am creating a simple form in java swing which consists of 1 JLabel, 1 JTextField, and 1 Button

```
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|           JLabel          |
|                           |
|---------------------------|
|    JTextField    | Button |
|---------------------------|
```

The Button should be in the bottom-right corner, the JTextField left of it, the JLabel on the top, spanning both columns

I want the Button to be a fixed size, the JTextField a fixed height, but using the full width (except for what is in use by the Button), and the JLabel using all other space (with and height)

I am not even sure if i should use a GridBagLayout or another Layout ?

This is probably a very easy question, but got me puzzled for quite some time (too many options with the GridBarLayout i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is a demo code that should get you going:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGridBagLayout {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestGridBagLayout.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("A button");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("A cool long nice label that will stretch.");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;// Fill the "cell" in both direction
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;// Allocate extra-width to the label
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;// Allocate extra-height to the label
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;// The label takes all the available width of the "row"
        panel.add(label, gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0; // Don't stretch TF vertically
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Fill horizontally
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        panel.add(textField, gbc);
        gbc.weightx = 0; // No extra horizontal space is given to the button
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE; // No fill for the button
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGridBagLayout().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! this works perfectly! (it only showed some space under and above the textfield, but changing its fill to both solved that .. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, set the layout of your panel to `GridBagLayout`.

Then, create a `GridBagConstraints` object and set the fill to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`.

For the `JLabel`, set the following properties on the constraints object: `gridx = 0, gridy = 0, gridwidth = 2, gridheight = 2, weightx = 1, weighty = 1`.

For the `JTextField`, set the following properties on the constraints object: `gridx = 0, gridy = 1, gridwidth = 1, gridheight = 1, weightx = 1, weighty = 0`.

For the `JButton`, set the following properties on the constraints object: `gridx = 1, gridy = 1, gridwidth = 1, gridheight = 1, weightx = 0, weighty = 0`.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

with your GridBagConstraints all components are shown on the same line (in the center of the screen)

[space][JTextField][JLabel][space][Button]

Comment: i guess i should use gridwidth.REMAINDER and gridwidth.RELATIVE .... but i tried lots of combinations and it always messes things up :) ... it seems BorderLayout with 2 panels might be the way to go .. or a BorderLayout with 2 panels, and a GridBagLayout inside the bottom (south) panel .. although that seems rather complicated and overdoing something which should be quite simple ?

Comment: @Hrqls I added an example of how to do it with GBL and RELATIVE/REMAINDER.

Answer (score 2):

Class BorderLayout is easy to use, less powerful than GridBagLayout.

But when thing are simple, solution have to be the same.

```
panel.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );
JPanel south = new JPanel();
south.add( textfield );
south.add( button );
button.setPreferredSize( x, y );
panel.add( south, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
```

Comment: Calling setPreferredSize is always running right in the middle of problems.

Comment: The OP says "I want the Button to be a fixed size"

Comment: it's not because you don't set a preferred size that the size will change over time (this mainly depends of the chosen LayoutManager and its constraints). Just don't set the preferred size.

Comment: @Hrqls in this solution, JTextField will not take the entire available width.

Comment: i see the solution might be with 2 panels .. nice didnt think of that ... the button doesnt have to be an exact fixed size (sorry for the confusion), i just dont want it to resize when the panel is resized, but the JTextField should grab all available space on that line .... with the code you posted the JLabel is perfect!, the JTextField and Button arent filling the space though .. i guess i should add the Button as EAST, and the JTextField as CENTER ?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet : indeed, the JTextField is just its own small size with a lot of space to the left, and the Button is the correct size, but not on the right-most position on the line (there is some space after it)

Comment: @Hrqls The solution suggested by Dan should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet : i tried it, but all was on the same line (due to the gridwidth i assume) ... thanks for your code (and very useful comments in it)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is a common thing to do, but below is code which is working (mainly code from Dan and Guillaume)

```
    //show stuff
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    //show label
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;           // Fill the "cell" in both direction
    c.weightx = 1.0;                            // Allocate extra-width to the label
    c.weighty = 1.0;                            // Allocate extra-height to the label
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; // The label takes all the available width of the "row"
    add(mlblShow,c);
    //show cmd txt
    c.weighty = 0;                              // Don't stretch TF vertically
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;           // Fill horizontally and vertically
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    add(mtxtCmd,c);
    //show send button
     c.weightx = 0;                             // No extra horizontal space is given to the button
 c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;          // No fill for the button
    add(cmdSend,c);
```